# ¿Cómo llamar un método?

Tags: java

Quiero llamar el siguiente método en el método al Main, pero no sé cómo:

```
public class Metodos {
    public void Pikachu (){
        Electricos Pikachu = new Electricos ("Pikachu", "Eléctrico", "Hembra", 3, "Volador, Agua", "Tierra, Planta, Eléctrico, Dragón", "Volador, Acero, Eléctrico", "Tierra", "Centrales Eléctricas, Zonas Industriales");
        System.out.println(Pikachu.getNombre());
        System.out.println(Pikachu.getTipo());
        System.out.println(Pikachu.getGenero());
        System.out.println(Pikachu.getNumEvoluciones());
        System.out.println(Pikachu.getFuerteContra());
        System.out.println(Pikachu.getDebilContra());
        System.out.println(Pikachu.getResistenteA());
        System.out.println(Pikachu.getVulnerableA());
        System.out.println(Pikachu.getHabitat());
    }
```

Intenté esto:

```
//Pikachu
 Metodos Pikachu = new Metodos ();
 Pikachu.Metodos();
```

Pero me marca error en Pikachu.***Metodos***();
Ayuda por favor :c Sé que es algo simple pero recién comienzo a utilizar los atributos, métodos y herencia.

Answer (score 1):

Debe ser así:

```
Metodos m = new Metodos();
m.Pikachu();
```

La clase es **Metodos**, **m** es un objeto de la clase metodos, por lo tanto tiene acceso al metodo `Pikachu()` que se encuentra dentro de su clase correspondiente.

Te sugiero que el nombre de los metodos los escribas con minuscula al inicio, asi como el nombre de objetos y variables.

Comment: Gracias! :D Funciona